Cannot get this code to work. Tensorflow - custom loss function cannot process Keras intermediate Tensor
Here is the code it is a simple Tensorflow code to train multiple MLP first produce a set of weights use these as inputs to an autoencoder which is trained to encode the truth table for an XoR then the decoder is trained to reproduce the weights.
The problem I am having is Keras will not allow me to pass the encoder output to the loss function.
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

# First, create and train multiple MLPs on XOR to get weight samples
def create_xor_mlp():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        Dense(4, activation='relu', input_shape=(2,)),
        Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
    return model

# XOR data
X = np.array([[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]])
y = np.array([[0], [1], [1], [0]])

# Train multiple MLPs to get different weight configurations
num_mlps = 100
weight_samples = []
for _ in range(num_mlps):
    mlp = create_xor_mlp()
    mlp.fit(X, y, epochs=1000, verbose=0)
    
    # Extract and flatten weights
    weights = []
    for layer in mlp.layers:
        w = layer.get_weights()
        weights.extend([w[0].flatten(), w[1].flatten()])
    weight_samples.append(np.concatenate(weights))

weight_samples = np.array(weight_samples)

# Create truth table target matrix
# Each row represents the full truth table [0,1,1,0]
truth_table = np.tile(y.T, (num_mlps, 1))

# Build modified autoencoder that maps weights to truth table
input_dim = weight_samples.shape[1]
truth_table_dim = 4  # Number of entries in XOR truth table

# Encoder (maps weights to truth table representation)
input_layer = Input(shape=(input_dim,))
encoded = Dense(16, activation='relu')(input_layer)
encoded = Dense(8, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(truth_table_dim, activation='sigmoid', name='truth_table_output')(encoded)

# Decoder (reconstructs weights to ensure meaningful encoding)
decoded = Dense(8, activation='relu')(encoded)
decoded = Dense(16, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(input_dim, activation='linear', name='weight_reconstruction')(decoded)

# Custom loss function to balance truth table prediction and weight reconstruction
def combined_loss(truth_table_weight=0.7):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        # MSE for weight reconstruction
        reconstruction_loss = K.mean(K.square(y_true - y_pred))
        # BCE for truth table prediction
        truth_table_loss = K.binary_crossentropy(K.flatten(truth_table), 
                                               K.flatten(encoded))
        return truth_table_weight * truth_table_loss + (1 - truth_table_weight) * reconstruction_loss
    return loss

# Create and compile model
autoencoder = Model(input_layer, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=combined_loss(0.7))

# Train the model
autoencoder.fit(
    weight_samples, 
    weight_samples,
    epochs=1000,
    batch_size=32,
    verbose=0
)

Here is the error:
 raise TypeError(

    TypeError: You are passing KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='Placeholder:0', description="created by layer 'tf.cast_14'"), an intermediate Keras symbolic input/output, to a TF API that does not allow registering custom dispatchers, such as `tf.cond`, `tf.function`, gradient tapes, or `tf.map_fn`. Keras Functional model construction only supports TF API calls that *do* support dispatching, such as `tf.math.add` or `tf.reshape`. Other APIs cannot be called directly on symbolic Kerasinputs/outputs. You can work around this limitation by putting the operation in a custom Keras layer `call` and calling that layer on this symbolic input/output.

I understand that passing a Keras intermediate Tensor is incompatable with a custom loss function like this. However I would like to know of a work around for this problem. Thanks

The error message indicates that you're passing a symbolic Keras tensor (KerasTensor) to a TensorFlow API that doesn't support symbolic dispatch. To resolve this, compute the truth table loss directly on the final decoded output by adding a custom layer to the model rather than calculating the truth table loss on intermediate encoded tensors.
